# Static file not being served to my individual blog pages

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I am having trouble with serving a css file to the individual blog posts in the blog portion of my website.

So the way it works:
Go to /blog- you get the blog page and that works fine.

But when I am trying to get to, for example, `/blog/post1` I am getting an error
`http://localhost:4000/blog/static/css/style.css`

I'd appreciate the help because I'm pretty new to express and routing files around and around. Cheers.

My file structure looks like this

    `blog
        /node_modules
        /src
            /mock
            /public
                /css
                    style.css
            /templates
                /partials
                    _head.jade
                    _nav.jade
                blog.jade
                index.jade
                layout.jade
                post.jade
            app.js`

So the way it works:
Go to /blog- you get the blog page and that works fine.

But when I am trying to get to, for example, `/blog/post1` I am getting an error
`http://localhost:4000/blog/static/css/style.css`

Here is what my respective files look like, maybe I'm missing something:

app.js

```
"use strict";

var express = require("express"),
    posts = require("./mock/posts.json");

var postsLists = Object.keys(posts).map(function(value){
    return posts[value]
    });

var app = express();

app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/templates");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/blog/:title?", function(req, res){
    var title = req.params.title;
    if (title === undefined) {
        res.status(503);
        res.render("blog", {posts: postsLists});
    } else {
    var post = posts[title] || {};
    res.render("post", {post: post} );
    }
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1>About Page</h1>");
})

app.get("/projects", function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1>Projects Page</h1>")
})

app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log("Frontend server is running on port 4000.")
});
```

_head.jade

```
head
meta(charset="UTF-8")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="static/css/style.css")
```

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
include ./partials/_head.jade
body
block content
```

blog.jade

```
extends ./layout

block content
    section(id="postHolder")
        for post in posts
            div.post
                h2 #{post.title}
                p #{post.body}
                a(href="/blog/" + post.title)
                    button Read More
```

post.jade

```
extends ./layout.jade

block content
    section
            div.post
                h2 #{post.title}
                p #{post.body}
                p This is the actual post page itself.
```

Comment: what happens if you change `link(rel="stylesheet", href="static/css/style.css")` to `link(rel="stylesheet", href="public/css/style.css")`?

Comment: All my CSS stops working on all of my pages. That is taken care of on line 12 of my app.js `app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))`

Answer (score 3):

I guess doing this will get you there -

```
head
  meta(charset="UTF-8")
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/style.css")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I want to draw your attention to my _head.jade file:

```
head
meta(charset="UTF-8")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/static/css/style.css")
```

I needed to make a reference to the absolute path and add the "/" in front of "static"

It used to be `static/css/style.css` and now it's
`/static/css/style.css` I'm pretty new to this and I don't know if I explained the reference to the absolute path correctly.